# Find the next polynomial in the sequence $x-1, x+1, x^2+x+1, x^2+1,...$

Tags: polynomials

Given the following sequence of polynomials:

\begin{gather*}
x-1 \\
x+1 \\
x^2+x+1 \\
x^2+1 \\
x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \\
x^2-x-1 \\
x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\\
x^4+1 \\
x^6+x^3+x+1\\
x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 \\
x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \\
 \,\,?
\end{gather*}

What will be the next polynomial in the sequence?

Comment: Look for cyclotomic polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is the sequence of [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), the next polynomial is just $$\Phi_{12}(x)=x^4-x^2+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Refer to cyclotomic polynomials.Next polynomial in the sequence is
$\Phi_{12}(x)=x^4−x^2+1$.